# Contact form 7: only send an automatic email if the field value is bigger than 8

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am setting up a form in WordPress using Contact form 7.
I need to send an automatic email to the users only if a certain field in the form has the value that is bigger than 8. Could anyone explain to me how to do it?

I look at many blogs in the internet and I found that I may need the setting "skip_mail: on". However, I am not very confident with javascript. Is there a way to set without coding ?

Many thanks in advance and best wishes,
W.

Answer (score 0):

This will need code modification in the contact us plugin. Whatever name you have given to your field, you need to fetch it and assign it to variable. After that, you need to add an `if` condition inside the contact form plugin, where email trigger code is written.

For eg the variable name you gave was `$number` then the condition will be something like:

```
if(strlen($number)>8)){
// here the email trigger code will come
}
```

If you need more help you can paste the contact form structure here then i can give you the precise code for this to work.